# Convert an vector to a specific color for `plot()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, legend

Below is a minimal working example.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(926)
df <- data.frame(x. = rnorm(100),
                 y. = rnorm(100),
                 color. = rnorm(100))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x., y = y., color = color.)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(option = "C")
p

p_build <- ggplot_build(p)

# The desired vector is below somehow I feel there must have an easier way to get it

p_build[["data"]][[1]][["colour"]]

df$color_converted <- p_build[["data"]][[1]][["colour"]]
```

Specifically, I like to use `viridis::viridis(option = "C")` color scheme. Could anyone help with this? Thanks.

****Modify****

Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. Let me put it this way, I couldn't utilize `ggplot2` package and had to use the pure `plot()` function that comes with `R`, in my specific project.

My goal is to try to reproduce the above plot with the base `R` package.

```
plot(df$x., df$y., color = df$color_converted)
```

If possible, could anyone also direct me on how to customize a gradient legend that is similar to `ggplot2`, with base `legend()`?

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't really follow what you want. Do you want to change the points with a specific color?

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to convert `color.` vector in `df` to match with `scale_color_viridis(option = "C")`, output the exact hex color.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can assign the colors to a vector called "color2" and use `scale_colour_gradientn` to assign these colors to your plot. The problem is that the colors are not sorted right so you have to do that first by using the `TSP` package. In the output below you can see that you can recreate the plot without using `scale_color_viridis`:

```r
set.seed(926)
df <- data.frame(x. = rnorm(100),
                 y. = rnorm(100),
                 color. = rnorm(100))

library(ggplot2)
library(TSP)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x., y = y., color = color.)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  viridis::scale_color_viridis(option = "C")
p
```

[image]

```r
p_build <- ggplot_build(p)

# The desired vector is below somehow I feel there must have an easier way to get it
color2 <- p_build[["data"]][[1]][["colour"]]

rgb <- col2rgb(color2)
lab <- convertColor(t(rgb), 'sRGB', 'Lab')
ordered_cols2 <- color2[order(lab[, 'L'])]

ggplot(df, aes(x = x., y = y.)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = color.)) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = ordered_cols2, guide = "colourbar")
```

[image]

```r
  #viridis::scale_color_viridis(option = "C")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Base r**

You can use the following code:

```
color2 <- p_build[["data"]][[1]][["colour"]]

rgb <- col2rgb(color2)
lab <- convertColor(t(rgb), 'sRGB', 'Lab')
ordered_cols2 <- color2[order(lab[, 'L'])]

layout(matrix(1:2,ncol=2), width = c(2,1),height = c(1,1))
plot(df$x., df$y., col = df$color_converted)

legend_image <- as.raster(matrix(ordered_cols2, ncol=1))
plot(c(0,2),c(0,1),type = 'n', axes = F,xlab = '', ylab = '', main = 'legend title')
text(x=1.5, y = seq(0,1,l=5), labels = seq(-3,3,l=5))
rasterImage(legend_image, 0, 0, 1,1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your insightful tip about the ordering. I think my question wasn't clear enough, please refer to the modified version if interested. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi @yuw444, I added some code to recreate the plot in base R!